# How to create a change rate function

Tags: ms-access, vba

Trying to create a function in VBA so that I can just query a table (tblGeoData) and use the function for field (lngPopulation).  The table (tblGeoData) has multiple rows, one for each year (field in tblGeoData = lngYear).  The required years would be defined with a Global Const (lngDataYr).  So the function would grab tblGeoData.lngPopulation where tblGeoData.lngYr = lngDataYr, lngDataYr-1, lngDataYr-2.  Thus, if the Global Const lngDataYr is set to 2014 then the function would grab lngPopulation for years 2014, 2013, and 2012.  Then, calculate an average change rate using the 3 values of lngPopulation (shorten to pop for brevity):

AvgChangeRate = ((pop of 2014 - pop of 2013)/pop of 2013 + (pop of 2013 - pop of 2012)/pop of 2012)/2

Uncertain exactly how to create this function but I picture it being able to be used for any field, not just lngPopulation and it would have 2 arguments, 1 is the field and the other is criteria to specify which rows. Possibly, I could query for the rows first (say the Global Const is called with a function named GetlngDataYr:

```
SELECT tblGeoData.lngPopulation
FROM tblGeoData
WHERE tblGeoData.lngYear In(GetlngDataYr(),GetlngDataYr-1,GetlngDataYr-2);
```

But it would be nice for the function to pull the data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just retrieve the three values and do the calculation:

```
Public Function PopRate() As Double

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim AvgChangeRate As Double
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim Pops As Variant

    SQL = "SELECT lngPopulation As pop FROM tblGeoData WHERE lngYear Between GetlngDataYr() And (GetlngDataYr() - 2) Order By lngYear Desc;"

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
    ' Copy values to array.
    Pops = rs.GetRows(3)
    rs.Close

    AvgChangeRate = ((Pops(0, 0) - Pops(0, 1)) / Pops(0, 1) + (Pops(0, 1) - Pops(0, 2)) / Pops(0, 2)) / 2

    Set rs = Nothing

    Poprate = AvgChangeRate

End Function
```

Comment: To the beginning of your code, I added: 'Public Function PopRate() As Double'.  To the end of your code, I added: 'End Function'.  This returned zero so I changed the function name from PopRate to AvgChangeRate.  This returned an error about declarations so I deleted 'Dim AvgChangeRate As Double'.  It now works as expected.  Does the function name need to be equal to the name of the output?

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the answer to hold the full function as I would write it.